# Polygon to raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rasterization

I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1. for my research I need to convert a polygon shapefile ( consisting polygons extracted from google earth) to raster. I am using the  "polygon to Raster" tool. The output cell size is 30m. But after I conduct the operation there are 4 horizontal lines on the raster. I've tried several times but same results.

Below is a screenshots.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try running the Repair Geometry tool on the polygons before using the Polygon to Raster tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other software creating polygons (so outside the ArcGIS system) cannot guarantee to conform to Shapefile specifications. What you are observing is almost certainly the result of malformed geometry, for example the vertices order is in the wrong direction.  As [@user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330987/polygon-to-raster#comment539987_330987) suggests run a repair geometry tool on the data first, this should fix it.

Comment: thanks. it worked  :)